# How to check if MS linked server is using SSL

Tags: ssl, sql

I use MS SQL server with valid certificate and with encryption turned on. I added linked server using this script:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'server', @srvproduct ='', @provider='SQLNCLI', @datasrc = 'server.domain.org\sqlexpress,1433', @provstr = 'Encrypt=yes;'
```

I would like to know if my connection is really encrypted. I tried to use:

```
select session_id, net_transport, protocol_type, encrypt_option from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

but it doesn't show linked connections. Is there any way how to detect if linked server uses SSL encryption? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wireshark to look at the packets. If you see a bunch of encrypted packets flying across the wire to and from the servers on the ports you want, then you are in good shape.

You should also be able to identify what protocol is being negotiated (tlsv1.0 or higher). Shoot for tlsv1.2, the others are considered broken.

Uninstall wireshark from your server when you are done...